# Must I install every possible printer driver for RDP clients?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, drivers, printer

I have users connecting with remote desktop and some have things like Quicken which has a PDF driver installed on their machines at home.

We want them to be able to redirect to print at home, but do we have to really install something like Driver Amyuni Document Converter 300, when it will never be used in anyway. The event log certainly believes it is worth contacting an administrator to install before logging in again.

Comment: Did you actually get a warning of the missing driver? Amyuni PDF Converter is a certified driver, hence it is available through Windows Update. It should be installed "automagically" if needed.

Comment: The events log, warns: Driver Amyuni Document Converter 300 required for printer Quicken PDF Printer is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long Answer: No, but you will need to install a third party redirection tool such as Thinprint or Screwdrivers to handle printer redirection. Windows Server 2008's RDS overcomes this with a tool called EasyPrint which is built into the OS and all later RDP clients (although it has its fair share of trouble), so if upgrading is an option then that might be the best way to handle it. A Server 2008 R2 Standard license is about the same cost as purchasing ThinPrint for a single server, so it might even make economic sense.

You only need to install the printer drivers if the printer is actually going to be used though. If you don't have the driver for `AcmePrint SuperCheap 9000 InkConsumer`, then the user can still safely connect and you can ignore those event logs, but keep in mind they won't be able to print to that printer.

Comment: I have had no issues at all with print redirection working. I only wondered if I hsad to worry about the dire warning of impending doom for a missing driver they wouldn't attempt to use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop should have a driver that redirects their printer to the server under "Remote Desktop Printer" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

configure the printer to the network (print server) with ad authentication which users should be able to install the printer if users take a rdp sessions also then he /she will be able to access the printers easily.. can avoid installing the printer drivers on all the rdp systems.